# Linq to SQL where clause with varchar as xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to do a select with Linq to SQL. A column which is of varchar type needs to be converted to XML and I need to evaluate the first element value to see if it is equal to a value I am passing into a method.

Here is the working SQL statement:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetQueuedMsgs]
    @FirstSMSRoute VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN   

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE  tblCommsQueue 
     SET isInProcess=1
    OUTPUT                  
        inserted.QueueID,
        inserted.CommsGuid,
        inserted.ValidityDT,
        te.EncodingType,
        inserted.DestAddress,
        inserted.Msg,
        '' as RoutingLabel,
        inserted.SubmittedDT,
        inserted.SendDT,
        inserted.SystemID,
        inserted.BusinessID,
        inserted.smsRoute,
        inserted.EncodingTypeID,
        inserted.RequestingIP
FROM tblCommsQueue tq   WITH(HOLDLOCK )
JOIN tblEncodingType te
ON tq.EncodingTypeID=te.EncodingTypeID
WHERE       
    SendDT<=GETDATE() 
    AND CommsTypeID=1 
    AND isInProcess=0
    AND CAST(CAST(smsRoute as ntext) as xml).value('(/ArrayOfSMSRoute/SMSRoute)[1]','varchar(260)')=@FirstSMSRoute
```

END

The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
    <ArrayOfSMSRoute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
        <SMSRoute>BGWASP</SMSRoute>
        <SMSRoute>Grape</SMSRoute>
        <SMSRoute>iliveit</SMSRoute>  
</ArrayOfSMSRoute>
```

and the linq to SQL statement, what am I doing wrong? The problem is with the xml part of the where clause.

```
var results = from RN in mdc.tblCommsQueueTests
                          where
                            RN.CommsTypeID == 1
                            && RN.isInProcess == false
                            && RN.SendDT <= DateTime.Now
                            //&& XDocument.Parse(RN.smsRoute).Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == FirstRoute.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Name == FirstRoute.ToString()
                            && (from r in XDocument.Parse(RN.smsRoute).Descendants().Elements("smsRoute")  select r.Value ).FirstOrDefault() == FirstRoute.ToString()
                          select RN;
```

Comment: what problem does LINQ code has ?

Comment: It does not throw an exception but when leaving in that line I dont get any results back

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `'(/ArrayOfSMSRoute/SMSRoute)[1]'` in the where clause of your update command :

if you want to extract the value of the first <SMSRoute> element beneath <ArrayOfSMSRoute> it should probably look like so :

```
'(/ArrayOfSMSRoute/SMSRoute[1])'
```

Notice the new position of the closing ')' bracket.